# GDB pretty printers for igraph_vector_t and igraph_matrix_t

Tags: c++, c, debugging, igraph, pretty-print

I'm using the C interface of igraph, and sometimes, while debugging I would like to see the content of some `igraph_vector_t` variables as well as `igraph_matrix_t`.

Is there some GDB pretty printer available like those available for STL containers ( `std::vector<T>` usually?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, but you can try calling `igraph_vector_print()` from within `gdb` if that is possible. Alternatively, you can access the `stor_begin` member of `igraph_vector_t` -- this is a pointer to the memory area that hosts the contents of the vector. `stor_end` points to the end of that area, and `end` points right after the last element of the vector - so, the "useful" part of the vector is between `stor_begin` and `end`.

Comment: I've solved by creating in the code stl vectors like this

`igraph_vector_t x //some vector`
`std::vector<igraph_real_t> xview(x.stor_begin, x.stor_end)` 
and then using the STL pretty printers.

In this way one can access the content of `x` using `xview` from within gdb.

Comment: Use x.stor_begin and x.end, not x.stor_end. The latter points to the end of the memory block allocated for the entire vector, but not all of the block is used all the time. The "real" end of the vector is at x.end.